# rename multiple files using glob with Python (file already exists)

Tags: python, for-loop, glob, file-rename, enumerate

I trying to rename multiple files inside a directory with Python, but the count inside for loop never update, so I get a "file already exists" error.

How can I get an updated variable (i) so that the name of the file is never repeated?

```
def change_name():

    for i, filename in enumerate(glob.glob(current_dir + '\packettest.txt')):
        os.rename(filename, os.path.join(current_dir, 'packettest_sent' + str(i) + '.txt' ))
        i = i + 1
```

This is the error that I get:

```
os.rename(filename, os.path.join(current_dir, 'packettest_sent' + str(i) + '.txt' ))
WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks to your comments, I understand what enumerate does, but the problem persist, i still equal 0. This is my full code:

```
import os.path
import sys
import glob
import time
current_dir = os.getcwd()
file_path = current_dir + "\packettest.txt"

#def main():

def change_name():

    for i, filename in enumerate(glob.glob(current_dir + '\packettest.txt')):
        os.rename(filename, os.path.join(current_dir, 'packettest_sent' + str(i) + '.txt' ))

def packet_listener():
    while not os.path.exists(file_path):
        time.sleep(1)
        print "waiting..."

    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        # read file
        change_name()
        time.sleep(1)
        packet_listener()
        print "OK"    
    else:
        raise ValueError("%s isn't a file!" % file_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    packet_listener()
```

Thanks for advance.

P.S.: sorry for my bad English

Comment: Don't use `i=i+1` when using `enumerate`

Comment: Can you put the list of the directory contents?

Comment: Thank you very much. Please check the code again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below (avoid incrementing i since enumerate already does it)

```
def change_name():
    for i, filename in enumerate(glob.glob(current_dir + '\packettest.txt')):
        os.rename(filename, os.path.join(current_dir, 'packettest_sent' + str(i) + '.txt' ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, replace this piece of code:

```
for i, filename in enumerate(glob.glob(current_dir + '\packettest.txt')):
    os.rename(filename, os.path.join(current_dir, 'packettest_sent' + str(i) + '.txt' ))
```

with this:

```
for i, filename in enumerate(glob.glob(current_dir + '\packettest.txt')):
    new_name = os.path.join(current_dir, 'packettest_sent' + str(i) + '.txt' )
    if os.path.isfile( new_name ) :
        print( 'file exists:', new_name )
    else :
        os.rename(filename, new_name)
```

And please, think twice about this: `enumerate(glob.glob(current_dir + '\packettest.txt'))`, what are trying to do? There's only one file, you don't use wildcards (`*`, etc), why you need a loop here and what results you re expecting?

Comment: In the directory, multiple files with the same name and the same format will be saved, so the idea is that the script is listening for a new one, and once it is detected, change the name so that it remains a record.

Comment: @androidBegginer ok, that sounds plausible, however, I'd rather use a bit different approach. thank you for answering, it makes sense =)